# Not receiving any ChangeStreamDocuments after performing an update to a collection using .net/c# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to debug why a watched collection is not returning any change stream document when iterating through the change stream cursor using the .net/C# driver? I'm not receiving any exception, and the code just keeps iterating through the batches of documents(`MoveNext()`) without any document in those batches (`cursor.Current.Count()`).

Prior to posting here, I checked if I could watch the exact same collection using mongoDB shell(mongosh), and I was able to successfully receive the update notifications using mongosh.

I'm using the exact same user to watch the same collection from .net/C# and mongosh

Following is a sample C# code used to perform the watch of a specific collection:

```
           var var _cursor = _collection.Watch()
            var updateResult = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, updateBuilder.Combine(updateList));

                while (_cursor.MoveNext() && _cursor.Current.Count() == 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in _cursor.Current)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            _cursor.dispose();

            return updateResult.ModifiedCount == 1;
```

Comment: why do you want to print only cases when `Current.Count() == 0`, I see no logic here.

Comment: I've tested your code in a sample, as soon as you remove `&& _cursor.Current.Count() == 0`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

so, it was a logic error, which I failed to realize in this case. I was too hung up on checking the count of each batch of change stream documents, which I think was unnecessary. The corrected code that worked in my case is as follows:

```
            var _cursor = _collection.Watch()
            var updateResult = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, updateBuilder.Combine(updateList));

                while (_cursor.MoveNext())
                {
                    foreach (var item in _cursor.Current)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            _cursor.dispose();

            return updateResult.ModifiedCount == 1;
```